# arm-eabi-gcc[1] syntax error: '@�4pO4' unexpected

Tags: java, android, gcc

I'm trying to execute gcc(copied from [this tarball](http://code.google.com/p/native-android-development/downloads/detail?name=android-gcc-4.4.0.tar.gz&can=2&q=)) on an android system, I get the following error:

```
arm-eabi-gcc[1] syntax error: '@�4pO4' unexpected
```

I'm executing the process like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh",
                                       "/android-gcc-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc",
                                       "--help");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/android-gcc-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc` is an ARM *binary* executable, but `sh file` makes sh to execute the binary as a [shell script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script).

You can simply call gcc itself. You may also want to set a [working directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) and/or [environment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment%28%29):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/android-gcc-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc",
                                       "--help");
pb.directory(new File("/"));
Process p = pb.start();
```